# Does "Delete Databricks Job" stop the code execution on the cluster immediately?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to know delete job works on Databricks. Does it immediately terminate the code execution on terminate the job cluster? If I am using micro-batching, does it make sure that the last batch is processed and then terminates or it is just abrupt termination which can cause data loss/data corruption? How can I avoid that?

Also what happens when i delete a job on a running cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will terminate immediately - not gracefully.

Are you using Structured Streaming or true micro batching? If the former then a checkpoint file will suffice in starting in the right place again. (https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/production.html)

If you have your own batch process you will need to manually write a checkpoint file to keep track of where you are up to. Given the lack of transactions I would ensure your pipeline is idempotent so that if you do restart and repeat a batch then there is no impact.

Comment: Thanks! I am using structured streaming as of now. I wanted to know the best practice from CI/CD point of view when we want to deploy a new build to Staging/Production server.